# SQL result missing a piece

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll get straight to the point. 
I've 2 tabels:

**1) poll_options**

```
| (ID)  |  Name   |
|  1    |  0-5    |   
|  2    |  5-10   |
|  3    |  10-15  |   
|  4    |  15-20  |   
|  5    |  20-25  |
|  6    |  25-30  |
|  7    |  30-35  | 
|  8    |  35-40  |
|  9    |  40-45  |
|  10   |  45-50  |
|  11   |  50+    |
```

**2) poll_votes**

```
| ID |  (poll_options_id) | vote_count | woning_id  |
| 1  |         3          |      1     |    20      |
| 2  |        11          |      1     |    18      |
| 3  |         5          |      1     |    25      |
| 4  |         5          |      1     |    27      |
| 5  |         3          |      1     |    25      |
| 6  |         4          |      1     |    26      |
```

Linking them together is the `ID` from `poll_options` with `poll_options_ID` from `poll_votes`. I placed `( )` around them to make is visual.

I've made a query to show the total votes made for each answer.

```
SELECT o.name as answer, sum(v.vote_count) as total_votes_per_answer
FROM poll_options as o LEFT JOIN poll_votes as v ON v.poll_option_id = o.id 
WHERE WONING_id='$woning_id'
GROUP BY o.name
ORDER BY o.id ASC
```

Here is where my problem is.
It only shows the `name` from `poll_options` that have a vote.
I would like to show all the `name` of `poll_options` and the ones where there is no vote yet, make them show 0.

for example (with current sql and woning_id=20):

```
| answer  |total_votes_per_answer|
|  0-5    |   1                  |
|  5-10   |   1                  |
```

What I want it to be:

```
| answer  |total_votes_per_answer|
|  0-5    |   1                  |
|  5-10   |   1                  |
|  10-15  |   0                  |
|  15-20  |   0                  |   
|  20-25  |   0                  |
|  25-30  |   0                  |
|  30-35  |   0                  |
|  35-40  |   0                  |
|  40-45  |   0                  |
|  45-50  |   0                  |
|  50+    |   0                  |
```

Is there something in SQL that I can use to get this result?

Comment: Your where clause is negating the left join.  so... WONING exist sin poll_votes.  It will be null on the left join so the where clause eliminates the null records.  Move the where limit to the join so it occurs as part of the join; allowing the left join to retain all the other options.

Comment: Edit my post with the answer

Comment: Gordon already provided the code, I was elaborating as to why. It has to do with order of operations. The joins occur, then the where clause executes.  Because of this the null value records created from the left join are then removed as they have 0 records in poll_votes meaning WONING will be null.  Null is not equal to 20 in your example so they are subsequently excluded.  To see this; remove your where clause and you'll see you get all records, move it to the join and you'll see only 20 with the rest being 0.

Comment: I know, I meant I edited the post with his answer

Comment: Generally you don't update your question with the accepted answer; you let the accepted answer be that. So that if someone has a similar problem they see what you were having trouble with and what answer helped you.

Comment: ok, noted. I'll delete the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL is invalid, but it would work if you inserted `and`:

```
SELECT o.name as answer, sum(v.vote_count) as total_votes_per_answer
FROM poll_options o LEFT JOIN
     poll_votes v
     ON v.poll_option_id = o.id AND WONING_id = '$woning_id'
GROUP BY o.name
ORDER BY o.id ASC;
```

That said, you should be passing `$woning_id` as a parameter into the query.  Don't munge query strings with such values -- they can cause unexpected and hard to find errors.